# How to create custom local variables in Varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using Varnish 7.4 OSS with no extra VMODs installed and for readability I'd like to store a computed value in a local variable, that I'll use a few lines later, within the same `vcl_*` step.

But I didn't find a way to do that in the docs.

I tried:

- `set v1 = "hello";`
- `new v1 = "hello2";`
- `STRING v1;`

But all gave an error.

The only variables I was able to add were HTTP headers, like `set req.http.v1 = "hello"`, but of course that stopped working as soon as I needed to store a TIME value.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

VCL has no native concept of variables. Therefor headers are often (ab)used instead: storing values in headers and reading those header values later. Either in the same subroutine or in another.

### Using headers and std.time()

If you want to store a time value, you can assign the string value via the `set req.http.x-some-time = "2024-07-08T08:49:37"` syntax and use the `std.time()` function to turn it back into a valid `TIME` type.

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/7.4/reference/vmod_std.html#std-time to learn more about the `std` VMOD and its `std.time()` function.

Don't forget to add `import std;` to your VCL file to make the namespace available to your VCL code.

### Using vmod_var

There is an open source VMOD called `vmod_var` that offers variable support in Varnish. You can download it from https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules. You'll have to compile it from source though.

See https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/vmod_var.vcc for the API and some code examples.

> Eventually we will provide packages for these VMODs on https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/, but for now compiling the VMODs from source is still required.

Comment: Thanks Thijs! May I suggest to add some information to the official docs? I hope I didn't miss them.

Comment: @watery Sure. Here's the GitHub repo/directory: https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/tree/master/doc/sphinx. Don't hesitate to send in some PRs.